# Is :[Interface] a valid array definition in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of code in my typescript codebase like this...

```
export interface SomeType {
    name: string;
}

export interface SomeComposedType {
    things: [SomeType];
}
```

This has been working fine but then I started running into issues with

> Property '0' is missing in type

and

> Argument of type 'SomeType[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[SomeType]'

I'm really confused about this now. I'm pretty sure that

```
let x:SomeType[] = []
```

is equivalent to

```
let x: Array<SomeType> = []
```

but is

```
let x:[SomeType] = []
```

also equivalent and correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. `[SomeType]` represents a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), i.e., an array with exactly one element of `SomeType`

`[string, number]`, for example, would match an array like `["test", 0]`

Comment: oh wow, now this message makes sense Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[SomeType]'.
  Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 1.(2322)
#ivebeendoingitwrong

Comment: Consider providing a documentation link for [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) in this answer.  Cheers!

Comment: I was getting mixed up with GraphQL's array syntax! Thx!

Answer (score 8):

no, `let x: [SomeType]` means that x is an Array of 1 element and that element is of type `SomeType`

if you need to declare an array that contains elements of `SomeType` just use one of the 2 forms you mentioned, `SomeType[]` or `Array<SomeType>`